# JavaScript Comparison the "if" keyword

Tags: javascript, if-statement

how can i check if a given number is "perfect square" with **if** Comparison?

Comment: 1) That's sort of opinionated 2) That's a completely separate question

Comment: The prompt returns a string so the input could be `"hello"` in which case the modulo would return `NaN`.

Comment: It's readable (minus the spelling errors) and pretty standard, so yes, it's good.

Comment: You need to print the number on a `<canvas>` via `ctx.fillText(number)` and then analyze the pixels - access them via `ctx.getImageData()` and check if the drawn number forms a perfect square by comparing the side length of the filled area.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand what you are asking, you can request the square root of a number first through [`Math.sqrt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt), and afterwards get the rest after division to see if it equals 0, in that case, the number can be divided by its square root, so is a "perfect" square

```js
function isSquare( number ) {
  // get the square root of the number in question
  var sqrt = Math.sqrt(number);
  // check if the modulo (rest after dividing  is 0)
  return ((number % sqrt) === 0);
}

console.log(isSquare(9)); // true
console.log(isSquare(5)); // false
```

To ask for the users age, it really depends on your use case. A prompt is a possible way to do it, though you could also do it by providing a form, which gives you the benefit of html5 input type `number`, like so:

```js
function checkAge() {
  var inputElement = document.getElementById('ageInput'),
    value = parseInt( inputElement.value ),
    outputElement = document.getElementById('output');
  if ( Number.isNaN( value ) ) {
    output.innerHTML = '<error>Please enter a valid number</error>';
    return;
  }
  if (value % 2 === 0) {
    output.innerHTML = 'Your age is even';
  } else {
    output.innerHTML = 'Your age is odd';
  }
}
```

```css
error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" id="ageInput" placeholder="give in your age" />
<button type="button" onclick="checkAge()">Validate</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way of checking if a number is odd is subjective. The way shown will certainly work. However, in actual code you need to be sure to catch invalid ages, either through checking if `age % 2` is `NaN` or by using something like `parseInt(prompt("what is your age?"), 10)`, then checking the output in `Number.isNaN`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(age % Math.sqrt(age) === 0) {
  console.log("Your age is a perfect square!");
}
```

i found the answer..thanks for everyone(:

Comment: Seen that you have 0 % acceptance rate for your questions, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Also, this is practically the same code as I have supplied so there was no need to add it as an extra answer